# Electrical load calculation for 1,300 sq foot condo

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

We are considering to install a heat-pump for heating and cooling and would like to get a better idea about any required upgrades to our electrical panel and house service. Below are pictures of our main and sub panel with labels. Our main panel currently is 100A but the panel is already wired for 120A (and the panel supports it as well). It is connected to the house service, which is 200AMP.

The **condo** is 1300 square feet with 2 bedroom, 1 bath. It is part of a three unit building with 200AMP service. The other two units have 100AMP panels.

Our **major appliances** include an electrical oven (3100W), washing machine (1300W), heat-pump dryer (1000W), dishwasher (1200W), and garbage disposal (720 W). We plan to install an induction cooktop soon (9600W).

Current **heating** is a gas furnace. For **cooling**, we have 2 window ACs.

##### Question

Would our current electrical service with the easy 120A upgrade allow us to install an air source heat pump for heating and cooling with 32k or 36k BTU?

Below is load calculation from [this](https://gensizer.assurancepower.com/index.php?option=com_aps&view=calculator&layout=wholehouse&Itemid=55) website recommended in an answer to another stack exchange question. That calculation would suggest yes but I am not sure about the numbers.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: You should have entered custom wattages for your actual appliances in the online calculator…. and I should point out that technically that’s not quite the NEC / CEC load calc but it’s a a conservative approximation.

Comment: In the US, "apartment" means it's a rental. In a rental, you shouldn't be making updates like this. I'd imagine that in other countries, you probably shouldn't make updates like this to a rental, either. Can you please clarify the use of the word "apartment". Do you actually own and have permission to make changes like this?

Comment: Thanks @FreeMan. I am not a native speaker and was not aware that apartment = rental. The unit is a condo. I edited the question with more details on that.

Comment: Many heat pumps have “emergency heat mode” this is when the temps get cold we would need the amount of electric heat in that case because this is a major draw on the electrical system, and even the easy bump to 120a  may not be enough.

Comment: We don't have a unit yet but I think it will require either a 40A or a 50A breaker with 230 voltage (depending on whether the unit is 30k or 36k BTU).

Comment: The 30-40amp 230v is the size of the heat pump compressor. Emergency heat if needed will be another 40-90 amps depending on your temp zone. The colder it gets the larger E heat requirements are. Some newer systems get down into the teens, if you keep the gas furnace you won’t need E-heat I had a friend that wanted to get rid of all gas. I talked him into keeping the furnace, he turned his furnace back on after his first December power bill , and he really thanked me in February when our temps dropped below zero, he said the difference was ~300$ he bought a fancy meter that chooses gas/elect.

Comment: @EdBeal Not sure but this sounds like an older system to me that requires costly electric backup heat. Newer cold-climate systems are much more effective. Something like the Mitsubishi MXZ-4C36NAHZ2 requires one 50 Amps breaker and is still working at -13F. But I am not an expert and will look into this more.

Comment: It was only a couple of years ago, mini splits also can get in the - range but the efficiency suffers at the lower temps the higher end inverter driven heat pump systems were so much more it made more sense to keep the gas and get a less expensive unit in his case.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, 1300 sq ft is quite small for a 120A service with a gas furnace. Houses of this size, with gas heating, have historically been fine with a 60A service.

Comment: Also the other calculator I forgot to mention is here: https://douglashelmer.com/calculators/electrical/residential-service/index.htm but keep in mind the CEC and NEC load calculation might be different.

Comment: It's your answer, feel free to edit that in, instead of making a comment which might get deleted at random.

Comment: 100 amp is the minimum sized service for a single family dwelling this has been code for many years no matter if gas or not NEC 230.79.C

Comment: @EdBeal I said historically… I know plenty of people with homes that were built between 1900 and 1950 that still have 60A service.

Comment: 1950 was prior to heat pumps and on demand electric water heaters and AC for residential . with a heat pump being considered and the appliances being electric not gas if the system they choose requires emergency heat the panel looks a bit undersized. But we don’t have all the facts and this is a question and answer.